# Where can i download Googles android package? (Not the apps)

Tags: android, gradle, repository, android-support-library, android-package-managers

Where can i download the jar file for `com.android.support` packages such as `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` or `com.android.support:design` ?

I looked at `mavenCentral` and `jCenter` but there was nothing there.

EDIT:

probably `get` wasn't the right word to use. i want to download them and use them offline.

Answer (score 1):

YOu can get it from gradle. If you are using Android Studio just go to build.gradle and add the following under depedencies

```
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
```

Comment: Sorry, probably `get` wasn't the right word to use. i want to download them and use them locally, offline.